# Пометить загружаемые шаблоны в Smarty 3.1.8

Tags: php, smarty

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу пометить каждый загружаемый шаблон адресом шаблона, типа **<!-- /views/blocks/block_topic.tpl -->**
Не знаете как сделать такой хак? Smarty 3.1.8 (который идёт с LiveStreet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам же отвечаю на свой вопрос :)

Правим файл `smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php`, расположенный по адресу `www\engine\lib\external\Smarty\libs\sysplugins`. Находим строчку в функции `compileTemplate`:

```
...
$_content = $template->source->content;
...
```

И меняем на:

```
$_content = "\n\n<!-- START {$this->template->source->filepath}-->\n".$template->source->content."\n<!-- END-->\n";
```